# How to send file from Android device to other device through Bluetooth by code

Tags: android, bluetooth, file-transfer

I want to develop application that sends image/txt or any file from one android device to another none android device using Bluetooth.

Please anyone can give help or source code for that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the code from which you can send file via bluetooth from android device to any device.

```
btnOk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                txtContent = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtContent);
                imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

                viewToBeConverted = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);
                linearLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, file.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                try
                {
                    if(file.exists())
                    {
                        file.delete();
                    }
                    out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                }
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


                viewToBeConverted.setText(txtContent.getText().toString());
                viewToBeConverted.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

               // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " " + viewToBeConverted.getDrawingCache(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                txtContent.setText("");

                Bitmap viewBitmap = linearLayout.getDrawingCache();


                linearLayout.setVisibility(1);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(viewBitmap);

                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
                viewBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object

                byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();  

                try 
                {

                    out.write(b);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();

                    Intent intent = new Intent();  
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);  
                    intent.setType("image/png");
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file) );  
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
        });
```

Enjoy. :)

Comment: Can you post your full source code so that other can easily understood. Thanks.

Comment: please post the full source code so that anyone can understand easily whats going on..

Answer (score 0):

This application allows two Android devices to carry out two-way text chat over Bluetooth. It demonstrates all the fundamental Bluetooth API capabilites, such as:

- Scanning for other Bluetooth devices
- Querying the local Bluetooth adapter
  for paired Bluetooth devices
- Establishing RFCOMM channels/sockets
- Connecting to a remote device
- Transfering data over Bluetooth

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html

Comment: This application send data to another android device but for that this application must be installed in both the devices. I want to send file from one device to another device from my application and that also works even another device not running our application. i.e. Receiver device also able to receive file using default Bluetooth.

Comment: Interesting, ill upvote your question and take another look when I have some more time on my hands.

Comment: @Jaydeep Khamar, I m doing bluetooth application, i also want to send file from one device to another(even not running our application). Could you share your solution?

Comment: If anyone have solution, post it here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913302/android-bluetooth-to-connect-another-bluetooth-device