# sending a mp3 file over bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth, mp3, send, transfer

I have a music file(mp3). I achieved sending a text over a Bluetooth connection but I'm not able send this mp3 file. I searched but couldn't get enough material on it. Please someone help me in this. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Do you mean you got an application that you're developing that uses bluetooth for transfert? Else this has nothing to do here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send file from Android device to other device through Bluetooth by code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227498/how-to-send-file-from-android-device-to-other-device-through-bluetooth-by-code)

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue yes in my  developing app ,I want to do it.

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant whether it'll work properly with mp3?

Comment: The file type should not matter. If it really does, describe HOW you successfully sent text, then what you did to send mp3, and describe HOW that failed, in detail.