# How to send image data to the other Bluetooth enable phone

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am developing Bluetooth based application; here I want to send text data as well as image. I am able to pair my device with the other Bluetooth enable phone, but even after successful pairing I am not able to send require data to targeted phone.

As of my search in Android we didn’t require any Headerset during transferring the data "<"just comparing J2me Bluetooth">".  Then how to send data to targeted phone?

The code snippet which I used after successful connection establishment with target phone is herewith.

```
clientSocket.connect(); //successfully connected with targeted phone

tmpOut = clientSocket.getOutputStream();//out stream opened

tmpOut.write(image, 0, image.length);//trying to send data, didn't get any exception

//closed clientsocket and outputstream
```

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227498/how-to-send-file-from-android-device-to-other-device-through-bluetooth-by-code) link

Comment: Thanks Vivek i follow the link which you mentione but for me "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921384/how-to-send-file-using-bluetooth-on-android-programatically" is working

Comment: put your own answer and accept that answer.