# Android app for Send file from android to other device using bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, file-transfer, mac-address, data-transfer

I want to send file from my android mobile device to another device but it should be done automatically, like I had a specific MAC address and also file path for that file so when I open the app it automatically sends that file to particular device(It is already paired). User doesn't allow to do anything. How can I achieve this? I want that after every 10 seconds that file is transfer from that to other device automatically.
If some one knows than it's really helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

I will give you some steps to do it

1. First, you have to make a timer in the first device which used to auto connect to the second device. It is good to use the Bluetooth Lib in 
   https://github.com/omaflak/Bluetooth-Library 
   Or his sample https://github.com/omaflak/Bluetooth-Android
2. After created a connection via socket. You will send file by TCP or UDP. I think it depends on you

[How to send file from Android device to other device through Bluetooth by code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227498/how-to-send-file-from-android-device-to-other-device-through-bluetooth-by-code?rq=1)
https://github.com/RamolaWeb/BluetoothSend

Comment: How to send a file using TCP or UDP? If you have some links or code than share with me.